# Как переопределить класс View для модуля Gii в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть `advanced` приложение из 3х частей.

- api
- backend
- frontend

В `backend` конфиге имеются такие настройки для кастомного `Gii` генаратора.

```
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => [
            'generators' => [
                'migrik' => [
                    'class' => \insolita\migrik\gii\StructureGenerator::class,
                    'templates' => [
                        'custom' => '@backend/gii/templates/migrator_schema',
                    ],
                    'migrationPath' => '@console/migrations/',
                ],
                'migrikdata' => [
                    'class' => \insolita\migrik\gii\DataGenerator::class,
                    'templates' => [
                        'custom' => '@backend/gii/templates/migrator_data',
                    ],
                    'migrationPath' => '@console/migrations/',
                ],
                'model' => [
                    'class' => ModelGenerator::class,
                    'singularize' => True,
                    'enableI18N' => True,
                    'generateQuery' => True,
                    'ns' => 'core\entities',
                    'queryNs' => 'core\entities',
                    'templates' => [
                        'default' => '@backend/gii/templates/model/default',
                        'expert' => '@backend/gii/templates/model/expert'
                    ],
                    'template' => 'expert'
                ],
                'crud' => [
                    'class' => CRUDGenerator::class,
                    'baseControllerClass' => 'yii\web\Controller',
                    'modelClass' => 'core\entities\\',
                    'controllerClass' => 'backend\controllers\\',
                    'enableI18N' => True,
                    'templates' => [
                        'default' => '@backend/gii/templates/crud/default',
                        'expert' => '@backend/gii/templates/crud/expert'
                    ],
                    'template' => 'expert'
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
```

Каким образом можно переопределить `yii\web\View` только для модуля Gii?

Способ:

```
'components' => [
    'view' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\extended\View',
        ],
    ]
```

Не подходит, потому что он переопределит все представлнния, для всего `backend` приложения.